# Fastest way to parse a csv file into a vector of vectors and then spit it back out?

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm trying to find the fastest method to reorder columns of a csv file (using the simple csv subset where there are no commas in cells). The reordering I'm doing through Vector.backpermute and that is fine; the bottleneck as indicated by RTS -p is the constructing of the vector of vectors that I do this operation on. The code below is the fastest version I could come up with. Anyone have any ideas?

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import           Control.Applicative
import           Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString            as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Builder    as BB
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy       as BL
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BL8
import           Data.Char
import           Data.Foldable
import           Data.Monoid
import qualified Data.Vector                as V
import           Data.Word
import           Debug.Trace
import           System.Environment
import           System.IO

data Args = Args { cols :: V.Vector Int, filePath :: FilePath } deriving (Show)

--
w8 = fromIntegral . ord
mconcat' :: (Foldable t, Monoid a) => t a -> a
mconcat' = foldl' (<>) mempty

parseArgs :: [String] -> Args
parseArgs [colStr, filePath] = Args ((\n -> n-1) . read <$> V.fromList (split ',' colStr)) filePath
  where split :: Char -> String -> [String]
        split d str = gosplit d str []
        gosplit d "" acc = reverse acc
        gosplit d str acc = gosplit d (drop 1 $ dropWhile (/= d) str) $ takeWhile (/= d) str : acc

reorder :: Args -> BL.ByteString -> BB.Builder
reorder (Args cols _ ) bstr =
  -- transform to vec matrix
  let rows = V.filter (not . BL.null) $ V.fromList $ BL.split (w8 '\n') bstr
      m = (V.fromList . BL.split (w8 ',')) <$> rows -- n^2
  -- reorder
      m' = (flip V.backpermute) cols <$> m
  -- build back to bytestring
      numRows = length m'
      numCols = length cols
      builderM = mconcat' . V.imap (\i v -> BB.lazyByteString v <> (if i < numCols - 1 then "," else "")) <$> m'
      builderM' = mconcat' . V.imap (\i v -> v <> (if i < numRows - 1 then "\n" else "")) $ builderM
  in builderM'

main :: IO ()
main = do
  args <- parseArgs <$> getArgs

  withFile (filePath args) ReadMode $ \h -> do
    csvData <- BL.hGetContents h
    BB.hPutBuilder stdout $ reorder args csvData
```

The program is invoked like: `$ reorder 2,1 x.csv` which says give me the second and then the first column for all the rows of that csv, so you can ignore the argument parsing bit.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you're working too hard. Manually building up and transforming all this data is error-prone and difficult to reason about (at least for me). [`cassava`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.5.0.0) is made for this kind of task.

I can't totally unwrap the structure of your data from the code you've presented, so I'm going to use a trivial example to demonstrate how to achieve the goal "reorder such and such column(s)".

Suppose you have a CSV describing a list of people and their ages.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import Data.Text
import Data.Csv
import Data.Vector

data Person = Person { name :: !Text , age :: !Int } deriving (Generic, Show)

-- We want to read and write TSVs

decodeOpt :: DecodeOptions
decodeOpt = defaultDecodeOptions { decDelimiter = fromIntegral (ord '\t') }

encodeOpt :: EncodeOptions
encodeOpt = defaultEncodeOptions { encDelimiter = fromIntegral (ord '\t') }

-- NB: Ideally, your encode and decode should be inverses, but these aren't
dec :: FromRecord a => HasHeader -> ByteString -> Either String (Vector a)
dec = decodeWith decodeOpt

enc :: ToRecord a => [a] -> ByteString
enc = encodeWith encodeOpt
```

Now we're gonna do some magic:

```
instance FromRecord Person

instance ToRecord Person where
  toRecord (Person name age) = record [ toField age, toField name ]
```

And now we can take

```
dec NoHeader "Roy\t30\r\nJim\t32" :: Either String (Vector Person)
```

and get

```
Right [Person {name = "Roy", age = 30}
      ,Person {name = "Jim", age = 32}]
```

And then reserialize them

```
enc [Person "Roy" 30, Person "Jim" 32]
```

with our result

```
"30\tRoy\r\n32\tJim\r\n"
```

So, this is all well and good assuming you're interested in just index-based column manipulation. If your CSV has column-names, you can be even more direct about things.

```
instance ToNamedRecord Person
instance DefaultOrdered Person
instance FromNamedRecord Person

-- NB: Ideally, your encode and decode should be inverses, but these aren't
decName ::FromNamedRecord a => ByteString -> Either String (Header, Vector a)
decName = decodeByNameWith decodeOpt

encName :: ToNamedRecord a => [a] -> ByteString
encName = encodeByNameWith encodeOpt (header ["age", "name"])
```

Now we can do this

```
encName [Person "Roy" 30, Person "Jim" 32]
```

and get

```
"age\tname\r\n30\tRoy\r\n32\tJim\r\n"
```

or

```
decName "name\tage\r\nRoy\t30\r\nJim\t32" :: Either String (Header, Vector Person)
```

to get

```
Right ( ["name","age"]
      , [Person { name = "Roy", age = 30 }
      , Person { name = "Jim", age = 32 }] )
```

Finally, if you really don't want any structure, `cassava` can deal with that, too.

```
dec NoHeader "Roy\t30\r\nJim\t32\r\n" :: Either String (Vector (Vector ByteString))
```

Which gives us

```
Right [["Roy","30"],["Jim","32"]]
```

And

```
enc [["Roy","30"],["Jim","32"]]
```

gives us

```
"Roy\t30\r\nJim\t32\r\n"
```

In this case, they're just regular lists, so you can do whatever transformations you like on the sublists to rearrange columns as you please.

Comment: hey thanks for the response! i actually tried cassava in my first few iterations but it was just so, so much slower...

Comment: Aww, that's disappointing. I was thinking about `pipes-csv`, too, maybe trying to exploit some streaming property so you can do your main operation on smaller sets of data. It looks like you're making one huge vector of vectors and then reordering the whole thing before writing it back to a ByteString. You might get better performance by only considering a single row at a time and streaming your results to the builder at the end rather than building a matrix only to break it down again.

Comment: yeah. i also tried that approach. still very slow. benchmark showed that all of the computation time was in cassava, hence me cutting it out and resorting to raw vectors, which still incurs a construction cost but a lesser one.

I havent tried pipes-csv because cassava was my biggest bottleneck when i was using it.

Comment: what i'm really looking for I guess is a way to create vectors fast and cheap by splitting input lines... I don't suppose you know of such magic?